Identify outer wall of the floorplan or building
For the floor plan of the building with 2 rooms (it can have more as well)

Is there Python or Java library which I can use to identify outer-wall (facade) of the building as polygon (a closed shape as drawn in below image), given that, I have shape information of all the rooms on the building floor (e.g. their coordinates and position) stored in PostGIS db. The number of rooms on the floor can be lot more than the example given here.


Depending on how precise the rooms are mapped you should get a more or less exact building shape poylgon by ST_Union'ing them with GROUP BY <building_id>. JTS provides that through the overlay API.

You can handle that directly in PostGIS, where you store those. The outer wall of a shape is ST_ExteriorRing(). As pointed out by geozelot, you can combine the rooms into one big shape with ST_Union() (or ST_MemUnion(), ST_UnaryUnion()), and get the exterior of that. If you want a Polygon with no holes rather than a LineString that follows the outer wall, you can pass that line into ST_MakePolygon(). Demo at db<>fiddle:

If the room shapes don't share vertices, meaning that they can be even very slightly shifted relative to each other, their union will be a MultiPolygon, not a single monolythic shape and the exterior will be a MultiLinestring.

If that's undesired, you can use ST_ConvexHull(), ST_ConcaveHull(), ST_AlphaShape() or ST_OptimalAlphaShape(), all of which will try to come up with a wrapper shape without you having to take a closer look at how the rooms wiggled away from each other.
They will be fine if you switch ST_Union() for a cheaper ST_Collect().
Here's an example of ST_ConcaveHull(st_makevalid(st_union(geom)),.1,param_allow_holes=>true)

You can also try to ST_Snap() those shapes together before merging if you want more control over how they melt together.

In python, using shapely, the union_all function will do the trick.
Sample code:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely import box
import shapely
import shapely.plotting as plot

room1 = box(20, 20, 40, 30)
room2 = box(40, 0, 50, 30)
house = shapely.union_all([room1, room2])

# Plot
plot.plot_polygon(room1, linewidth=6, facecolor="none")
plot.plot_polygon(room2, linewidth=6, facecolor="none")
plot.plot_polygon(house, linewidth=2, facecolor="none", color="red")

plt.show()

Plot:

